# how to change upload img url with cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

**i am use this code to upload image ..this code save uploads url into database table to reuase the url again to view image was uploaded..the problem is to change url that saved into database not to change upload folder (make short ulr to save) like this**

*from*

```
img/dvds/sunset.jpg
```

*to*

```
dvds/sunset.jpg
```

this change that i need make me use image() helper easy..

```
<?php
/**
 * App Controller
 *
 * file: /app/app_controller.php
 */
class AppController extends Controller {

    /**
     * slug()
     * creates a slug from a string
     */
    function slug($str) {
        // replace spaces with underscore, all to lowercase
        $str = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $str));

        // create regex pattern
        $pattern = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/";

        // replace non alphanumeric characters
        $str = preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);

    return $str;

}


    /**
     * uploads files to the server
     * @params:
     *      $folder     = the folder to upload the files e.g. 'img/files'
     *      $formdata   = the array containing the form files
     *      $itemId     = id of the item (optional) will create a new sub folder
     * @return:
     *      will return an array with the success of each file upload
     */
    function upload_files($folder, $formdata, $item_id = null) {
        // setup dir names absolute and relative
        $folder_url = WWW_ROOT.$folder;
        $rel_url = $folder;

        // create the folder if it does not exist
        if(!is_dir($folder_url)) {
            mkdir($folder_url);
        }

        // if itemId is set create an item folder
        if($item_id) {
            // set new absolute folder
            $folder_url = WWW_ROOT.$folder.'/'.$item_id;

            // set new relative folder
            $rel_url = $folder.'/'.$item_id;
            // create directory
            if(!is_dir($folder_url)) {
                mkdir($folder_url);

            }
        }

        // list of permitted file types, this is only images but documents can be added
        $permitted = array('image/gif','image/jpeg','image/pjpeg','image/png');

        // loop through and deal with the files
        foreach($formdata as $file) {
            // replace spaces with underscores
            $filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $file['name']);
            // assume filetype is false
            $typeOK = false;
            // check filetype is ok
            foreach($permitted as $type) {
                if($type == $file['type']) {
                    $typeOK = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // if file type ok upload the file
            if($typeOK) {
                // switch based on error code
                switch($file['error']) {
                    case 0:
                        // check filename already exists
                        if(!file_exists($folder_url.'/'.$filename)) {
                            // create full filename
                            $full_url = $folder_url.'/'.$filename;
                            $url = $rel_url.'/'.$filename;
                            // upload the file
                            $success = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $url);
                        } else {
                            // create unique filename and upload file
                            ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/London');
                            $now = date('d-m-Y-His');
                            $full_url = $folder_url.'/'.$now.$filename;
                            $url = $rel_url.'/'.$now.' - '.$filename;
                            $success = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $url);
                        }
                        // if upload was successful
                        if($success) {
                            // save the url of the file(i want to change this code)
                            $result['urls'][] = $url;
                        } else {
                            $result['errors'][] = "Error uploaded $filename. Please try again.";
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        // an error occured
                        $result['errors'][] = "Error uploading $filename. Please try again.";
                        break;
                    default:
                        // an error occured
                        $result['errors'][] = "System error uploading $filename. Contact webmaster.";
                        break;
                }
            } elseif($file['error'] == 4) {
                // no file was selected for upload
                $result['nofiles'][] = "No file Selected";
            } else {
                // unacceptable file type
                $result['errors'][] = "$filename cannot be uploaded. Acceptable file types: gif, jpg, png.";
            }
        }
    return $result;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: The description of `upload_files` says "$folder     = the folder to upload the files e.g. 'img/files'".  Do you need something different?

Comment: $result['urls'][] = $url;  this code save the url of the file into databse..i dont need to change upload folder..i just need to save the shourt url upload like this...dvds/sunset.jpg instead of img/dvds/sunset.jpg

Comment: i don't uderstand what are you trying to do, if the variable folder gives you the chance to do as you are asking. Instead of passing img/dvds in the variable folder just pass dvds.... or if you want to do it manually you may try `$tmp =  explode ('/',$folder); unset($tmp[0]); $folder = implode ('/', $tmp);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not simply change

```
 $result['urls'][] = $url;
```

to

```
 $result['urls'][] = substr($url, 4);
```